# In MySQL, what is the purpose of contains? can anyone give me it's usage with example?

Tags: mysql

I checked online resources for the use of `contains` in mysql, couldn't find anything. I tried the following query in my db.

`select * from test_table where contains (column_a, 'a');`, which returned 
`ERROR 3055 (HY000): Geometry byte string must be little endian.`.

Comment: There is no `contains` in MySQL. Where did you read it from?

Comment: @Darshan Mehta not so https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-relation-functions-mbr.html#function_contains no idea how it works though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use INSTR instead of CONTAINS.

SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE INSTR (column_a, 'a');

Answer (score 0):

Mysql doesn't have **contains** keyword. If you want to achieve that you should use **like** keyword. Eg.

```
Select * from someTable where field like '%something%'
```

Comment: I am aware of this solution. I was just trying to understand what `contains` does. Thanks anyways. The online resource by @P.Salmon is quite helpful.